# Why does groovy / gsp add additional html tags around output, and how to avoid that without workarounds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, groovy

I've got a groovy application that requests additional content from the server backend via jQuery and AJAX. That content is rendered from a gsp page that has the code for a html table and just that (read: it contains `<table>...</table>` and nothing else). When running on my localhost (Windows) (either accessing it as localhost or as www.example.com re-routed to it using an entry in etc/hosts) that content gets rendered and served all right, BUT when I deploy it to our servers, the result contains additional tags - it is: `<html><body><table>...</table></body></html>`.

I worked around that in JavaScript by editing the result as a workaround with: `result = result.replace("<html>","").replace("<body>","").replace("</html>","").replace("</body>","");` but I rather have a permanent solution that is the same for all servers.

**EDIT:**
Code I'm using to trigger rendering:

```
def model = [
    jobs: jobs, 
    onlyActiveJobs: onlyActiveJobs, 
    filters: params.filters]
if (forceShowAllJobs)
    model << ['filters': ['filterInactiveJobs': true]] 
if (!request.xhr){
    return model
}
else{
    render(template: 'jobTable', model: model)
}
```

Comment: what does your groovy code look like?

Comment: Just edited and added code that starts the rendering. Does that answer your question, @rdmueller ?

Comment: Usually different behavior between different servers is more of a configuration issue than coding issue. I would suggest you check any profile/config type of files.

Comment: I assume you use Grails to render your GSP? Have you tried to reproduce the behaviour by doing a `grails prod run-app`? Just to verify that it's not the difference between dev and prod environment...